# How can i specify that the type parameters of a class have to inherit the class itself? ( class A<T : A>{ __ } ) | Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, type-parameter

I have an abstract class with a type parameter:

```
abstract class AClass<T>(){ ___ }
```

however, I want to specify that the type `T` must be a child of `AClass` itself.

```
abstract class AClass<T : AClass>(){ ___ }
```

This doesn't work. I also tried:

```
abstract class AClass<T : AClass<*>>(){ ___ }
```

but the IDE gives me a `Finite Bound Restriction` Error.

Is it even possible to achieve the desired behaviour in Kotlin?

Comment: You want `T` to be a subclass of `AClass<U>`, where `U` is anything? Or do you just want `T: AClass<T>`?

Comment: yes, I want `T` to be a subclass of `AClass<U>`, where `U` is anything, thats why I tried `T : AClass<*>`

Comment: It is not possible to enforce this in Kotlin. There is no self type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though some other languages support this **self type param**, This is **not possible** in kotlin. Because it may lead to recursive generics. Kotlin team reported that implementation of this feature is difficult in accomodate with kotlin design. Also it feels too noisy to have self types.

**Useful Links:**

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6494#comment=27-882961

https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/self-types/371/86

https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/this-type/1421/10